# Swagger: Reusing an enum definition as query parameter

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I would like to use an enum defined in `definitions` as part of my parameter definitions in a query string.

I'm defining the Swagger Enum in the `definitions` part of my Swagger 2.0 spec file.

```
OperationType:
  type: string
  enum:
  - registration
  - renewal
```

I can create references to it in other definitions:

```
Operation:
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
    type:
      $ref: '#/definitions/OperationType'
```

I can use the `schema` tag to make a reference to it when the parameter is `in: body`, but not when it's `in: query`

```
    - name: operation
      in: body
      description: description
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/OperationType'
```

I tried dropping `schema:` and making a reference in `enum:` instead, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is possible in OpenAPI 3.0. All parameters now use a `schema`, and, by extension, can `$ref` the schemas.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...
paths:
  /something:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: action
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/OperationType'
      ...

components:
  schemas:
    OperationType:
      type: string
      enum:
        - registration
        - renewal
```

Answer (score 16):

For Swagger 2.0, we've limited the ability to use model definitions for anything but `body` parameters. The `definitions` section is used to define schema, which can also be used to define non-objects. However, those definitions can only be accessed where the `schema` keyword is used. As initially stated, `schema` not accessible for non-body parameters, and as such, cannot be used by query or path parameters, thus limiting the ability to reuse those definitions.

There's an [open feature request](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/issues/300) asking for it to be handled in a future version of the spec.

Comment: No, but it looks like in 3.0 it will be possible.

Comment: @Ron Looking forward to it. Seems really useful.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. Is there a resolution for this? I'd love to be able to reuse enum definitions across parameters.

Comment: The behavior changes in the next version of the spec.