# Swagger 2: use enum reference in query parameter of array type

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Can not get how to use reference of string type with enum values in array parameter.
I can make reference in items key and it is working, but Swagger produce error: Not a valid parameter definition

Web UI generates interface, but it have textarea instead of multiselect box I expected.

What is the proper way to do it?

My code:

```
    swagger: '2.0':
    paths:
      /test:
        get:
          parameters:
          - in: origin
            name: status
            description: Origin
            required: false
            schema:
              type: array
              items:
                $ref: '#/definitions/Origin'
            collectionFormat: pipes'
    definitions:
      Origin:
        type: string
        description: Campaign origin
        enum:
          - one
          - two
    externalDocs:
      description: Find out more about Swagger
      url: http://swagger.io
    host: virtserver.swaggerhub.com
    basePath: /
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array parameters with `items` containing `$ref` are [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255384/swagger-reusing-an-enum-definition-as-query-parameter) [supported](https://github.com/swagger-api/validator-badge/issues/81)  in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0. But it looks like [this will be possible](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/300) in the next version, 3.0. For now there are a couple of workarounds, see below.

Your spec also has some other issues:

- `in: origin` is not valid. The [`in`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameterIn) keyword specifies the parameter location (path, query, header, etc.) and only accepts certain values as per the OpenAPI/Swagger spec. I guess you meant `in: query` or `in: header`.
- Typos (or copy-paste errors?): `swagger: '2.0':` has an extra `:` at the end and `collectionFormat: pipes'` has an extra `'` at the end.

One solution for having an array parameter containing enum values is to define the enum inline:

```
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: status
          description: Origin
          required: false
          type: array
          collectionFormat: pipes
          items:
            type: string
            enum:
              - one
              - two
```

Another solution (found [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/300#issuecomment-77669429)) is to use YAML anchors to reference the enum. This is a feature of YAML where you can mark a key with `&anchor-name` and then further down use `*anchor-name` to reference that key's value.

```
definitions:
  Origin:
    type: string
    description: Campaign origin
    enum: &origin
      - one
      - two

paths:
  /test:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: status
          description: Origin
          required: false
          type: array
          collectionFormat: pipes
          items:
            type: string
            enum: *origin
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Swagger.json generated by project is returning same error since items has $ref. 

Can you help me how to remove $ref and add enum in c#? Project is net core 3.1.

Answer (score -1):

One option is to define a parameter and make a reference to that: (I had an issue with using reference ($ref:) within a query definition)

```
paths:
  /path:
    get:
      operationId: controllers.controller
      parameters:
        **- $ref: '#/parameters/SPEC'**


parameters:
  SPEC:
```