# Swagger YAML Query (type object) Parameter Definition Error

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor, swagger-codegen

I'm getting the following error:

> Schema error at paths./cards/count.get.parameters[0] is not exactly
>   one from <#/definitions/parameter>,<#/definitions/jsonReference>

Here is my definition:

```
  /cards/count:
    get:
      tags:
      - "cards"
      summary: "Number of Cards available"
      description: "Excludes cards which the user has answered correctly in the past."
      operationId: "countCards"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - name: "tagFilter"
        in: "query"
        description: "Input is optional - left blank will return all tags and a count"
        type: "object"
        properties:
          tags_any:
            type: "array"
            items:
              type: "integer"
              format: "int64"
              enum: [1,2,3]
          tags_all:
            type: "array"
            items:
              type: "integer"
              format: "int64"
              enum: [4,5,6]
          tags_not:
            type: "array"
            items:
              type: "integer"
              format: "int64"
              enum: [4,5,6]
```

I understand you can't use a schema definition as per this question:  [Swagger: Reusing an enum definition as query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255384/swagger-reusing-an-enum-definition-as-query-parameter)

What do I need to modify to make the YAML compile without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in query parameters are not supported in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, but are supported in OpenAPI 3.0.

If you stick with OpenAPI 2.0, you'll need to split the object into separate parameters, like so:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: tags_any
          type: array
          items:
            type: integer
            format: int64
            enum: [1,2,3]
        - in: query
          name: tags_all
          type: array
          items:
            type: integer
            format: int64
            enum: [4,5,6]
        - in: query
          name: tags_not
          type: array
          items:
            type: integer
            format: int64
            enum: [4,5,6]
```

In OpenAPI 3.0, you can define the parameter as object and use the [`style` and `explode`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/) keywords to specify how this object should be serialized.

```yaml
      parameters:
        - name: tagFilter
          in: query
          description: Input is optional - left blank will return all tags and a count

          # Send the object as ?prop1=value1&prop2=value2
          # This is the default serialization method for objects in query parameters
          style: form
          explode: true

          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              tags_any:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: integer
                  format: int64
                  enum: [1,2,3]
              tags_all:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: integer
                  format: int64
                  enum: [4,5,6]
              tags_not:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: integer
                  format: int64
                  enum: [4,5,6]
```

Comment: is it possible to use open API 3 within Swaggerhub?

Comment: @AllanBowe Currently no, but I would assume it's on the roadmap.

Comment: UPD: SwaggerHub now [supports OpenAPI 3.0](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/openapi-3-support).